# aurelia with system.js is not serving up utf-8

Tags: aurelia, systemjs

I am using Aurelia with system.js as the module loader.  If I place the following in an html file:

`<div>éèàç</div>`

The result that I see in the browser is the following:

����

I know that the html file is being saved as utf-8.  The Meta tag specifying utf-8 encoding is there.

Any clues how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my editor was *not* in fact saving with the UTF-8 encoding, though it was double-byte, which fooled me.  Had to do a Save-As in Visual Studio to figure that out.